# Error is(POST http://127.0.0.1/phpSajt/PHP/register.php 404 (Not Found))

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my jquery, problem is when i submit form data goes in register.php and then fill in database, but i have this error in console

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const BASE_URL="http://127.0.0.1/phpSajt/";

            $.ajax({
                url:BASE_URL+"PHP/register.php",
                method:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{
                    firstName:firstName,
                    lastName:lastName,
                    email:email,
                    password:password,
                    send:true
                },
                success:function(){
                   alert("Success");

                },
                error:function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log(error);
                    var poruka;
                    switch(xhr.status){
                        case 404:
                        poruka="Stranica nije pronadjena";
                        break;
                        case 409:
                        poruka="Podaci vec postoje";
                        break;
                        case 422:
                        poruka="Podaci nisu validni";
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        break;
                        case 500:
                        poruka="Greska";
                        break;
                    }
                    if(poruka){
                    document.getElementById("greske").innerHTML=poruka;
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("greske").innerHTML="";
                    }
                }
            });
            }
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you have a local webserver running?

Comment: Yes, i use xampp

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1/phpSajt/PHP/register.php` the correct path to the file that you have put there?

Comment: Yes, this page exists, i just don't know how data transfer to database, and my ajax have error

Comment: try replacing the ip for localhost and see if the xampp configured for port 80 or another port.

Comment: Same error, and xampp is configured for port 80, i checked in config